In pose mode move tool rotates instead of moves the leg
When in pose mode I select left leg and try to move it with Move tool it rotates instead of moves the leg. When I try to use Move tool with right leg it work fine. Is there any way to fix this problem?
Thanks for answering!
Anže


Since you haven't added any images of your model or settings or provided a Blend file to look at it's impossible to guess without further details. How to ask a good question.

Ok, sorry. I'm adding a picture now.
https://i.imgur.com/lZejT99.png

please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

My file: https://we.tl/t-qFkjdzxOjo =)

Your file won't load for me.  First thing I'd check would be transform locks or the "connected" property on the bone-- either of those will mean a move action gets reinterpreted as a rotation action.

In Transform->Location-> X, Y and Z were locked, but if I unlock them, the "yellow rectangle" of the foot moves, but the foot itself doesn't move. I'm not sure what is the second option you mentioned.
